# Is it possible to use a verb directly after a prepositional phrase?

Tags: grammar, prepositional-phrases

Is it possible to use a verb directly after a prepositional phrase? For example,
Is the sentence of "In this picture are some wonderful details" correct?
thanks

Comment: Hi Lee, I'm glad that you find my answer helpful. But please don't accept it too hastily. Read [this thread](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-an-answer) on meta.

Comment: Dear @user178049 so many thanks for attention. I think your answer is complete, on top of that when I faced with "inversion" suddenly I remember this sentence which I forgot "On the table was all the money we had lost". Moreover, your score is so high, hence It seems your answer should be right, am I right?

Comment: It doesn't have to have inversion. Consider "There are many activities on the beach for kids including riding donkeys", where "including" is a prep and "riding" is a verb. Note that prepositions can take clauses as complement as well as NPs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is called the subject-dependent inversion. Here's another example taken from Huddleston & Pullum (2002):

> Up in my room, on the nightstand, is a pinkish-reddish envelope that has to go out immediately.

However, keep in mind that the inverted version is less common than the non-inverted one, *some wonderful details are in this picture*. Or some speakers may opt for the existential version *there  are some wonderful details in this picture*. Since there are some pragmatic constraints that cannot be violated, writers don't invert the order for no reason.